# Which Marvel superhero has fought against the most fellow superheroes?

Tags: marvel

It seems throughout the comics there are a lot of confrontations between the "good guys", such as Thor & Iron Man in the first Avengers movie. Which "good guy/gal" character is most prone to fight with a fellow "good guy" superhero?  It seems like Cap is always in the middle of something.

Fighting a brainwashed/drugged/alt universe/etc version of a superhero doesn't count.

Comment: Hulk fought them all at once

Comment: You may not count him as a "good guy", arguably, but Punisher tends to get in lots of small fights with other heroes because they don't like him killing criminals.  But let's face it, there's a reason they make jokes about how teamups work in comics: usually first the heroes fight each other, then they team up to fight the badguy.  So the hero with the most teamups is probably most prone to fighting other heroes.  So I'd guess Spidey. :)

Comment: As it stands this is to broad. It needs to cover *either* the comics or the movies. Movies should be answerable.  Comics may still be too broad, and/or opinion based due to your wording "most prone to fight" do you want numbers,  or most antiheroic?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - I was thinking of number of different "good guys" fought, not the number of fights (e.g. Hulk fighting Cap  four different times counts as one). I was hoping for an answer like "hero X has fought Y number of good guys which is the most" I removed the MCU tag to make things less broad. I'm mainly interested in comics because that's what I know the least about.

Comment: deadpool killed them all?

Comment: Does repeatedly fighting the same person count each time? i.e. does every instance of Hulk fighting Wolverine count as 1 or the dozens of times they've fought?

Comment: @phantom42 - No. It would only count as one of the characters (Wolverine) fought. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a virtually impossible question to answer. If the heroes form teams, like in Civil War, then you've got a bunch of different heroes all fighting each other and their "Fought Hero" counts are very similar. And with all the different heroes it's too difficult to figure out which one of them has a slightly higher count than the others.

I assume we're talking about Earth-616, since you said alt universe don't count. Though if they did, then "Deadpool kills the Marvel Universe" and "Old Man Logan", in which one person kills pretty much everyone else are pretty good contenders.

Ultimately though, short of reading every comic of every hero and keeping a tally of all the different heroes they've fought, there's no way to really know. To be perfectly honest, I daresay that every hero has fought every other hero at some point during their storyline, so they've probably all fought each other anyway.

Comment: “"Old Man Logan", in which one person kills pretty much everyone else” — really? Does *Old Man Logan* really fit that description?

Comment: Technically he was being fooled by Mysterio's illusion, but he thought that the X-Mansion was under attack, and only upon killing the final "attacker" did the illusion lift, revealing that all the people he had killed were in fact his fellow X-Men. That's why I said "If we were considering Alternate Universes" and such, because if we were, then Old Man Logan has definitely fought and killed a lot of Marvel heroes (All of the X-Men), and ultimately killed Wolverine as a hero aswell, since he permanently sheathed his claws after the incident.

Comment: "Fighting a brainwashed/drugged/alt universe/etc version of a superhero doesn't count. " so none of these examples are applicable.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo: of course — I kind of forgot how many “all of the X-Men” is, excellent point.

Comment: Except that's moot because it's an alternate universe and he was fooled into killing them, rather than it being a straight up "I think something different to you" *Ensuing Fisticuffs*.

Comment: However, in a similar vein, it might be that one of the heroes in "Avengers vs The X-Men", in which there are a LOT of different heroes fighting, has got a particularly high number. I agree Donatello Swansino though, World War Hulk just wrecked everybody on his Illuminati-hating rampage.

Answer (score 0):

I would say Hulk, based on the World War Hulk storyline alone.

Comment: Why was he fighting everyone? Was he under an outside influence making him go postal or anything? Something like this wouldn't count per the original question.

Comment: Nope, no direct outside influence. He was enraged beyond belief at the Illuminati because he believed that they were responsible for the deaths of all the people on Sakaar, including his wife and child. This turned out not to be the case, and was actually Miek that brought about Sakaar's destruction.  So you might call that influence by Miek in the literal sense of the word, but nobody was controlling the Hulk's mind or anything. He was just really angry.

Comment: You would *say*, but could you at least give a reasoned estimate of how many that is, for comparison?